# Open Source OCR for Arabic

Tags: c#, image-processing, open-source, ocr

I'm looking for an OCR library or any samples that I could use it to read Arabic letters from an image.i googled  a lot and didn't find any thing..please help 
thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696180/open-source-ocr-library-for-arabic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825712/need-an-opensource-of-arabic-ocr-either-in-java-or-in-dotnet

Answer (score 7):

[TesseractOCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is the probably the best open source OCR engine out there and is very flexible as to what it can recognize. It allows for training with custom data, so essentially any language is possible as long as your willing to put in the work (i.e. create the training set).

There are [tools provided by tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/bbtesseract/) (with a gui interface) that can help create the data set where you specify the bounding box of characters and the corresponding transcription.

**EDIT:** Noticed from another post (linked above) that a training set on Arabic has already been created for version 3.01. You'd just need to plug in the Arabic data and your problem is solved :).

Answer (score 1):

You may try the [Abbyy Fine Reader](http://finereader.abbyy.de/), they may have the language you are looking for.

Comment: it's a closed library..i need an open source to do that

Comment: Maybe you should mention that in your question.
Finding an good open source OCR will be very difficult, especially for arabic.