# Need an open source of Arabic OCR either in Java or in .NET

Tags: c#, java, ocr

I have a requirement to recognize an Arabic name in Arabic text in Java or in .Net or any other language.  Well I googled on dotnet (Nuance) and in Java (Aspose). Both the things are good in reviews, but nuance is not providing trials for my R and D.  Aspose not supporting for Arabic. So my question is do we have any open sources for Arabic or any commercial products with at least a three days trial which converts Arabic image to text.

Comment: I do not fully understand it. You're looking for a software that takes an image containing arabic characters as input and returns the characters found in the image?

Comment: exactly but not a software , actually i am looking for an API

Comment: See also [Do we have any Arabic OCR in Java?](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2258457) at OTN (a cross-post).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson :- what it mean? both the posts are mine only.. i wantedly posted .. is there anything wrong?

Comment: It is generally considered polite when posting one question to many sites (or even 2), to mention that in each site, and to link to the other posts.  People don't like wasting time answering a question that might have already been answered somewhere else.  Their time is valuable.  By linking the questions, they can quickly check if an answer has already been supplied.  It is also (considered to be) your responsibility to keep each thread up to date on answers offered on other sites.  At least, that is how it works on the OTN - I am less sure of the 'right manners' for StackExchange sites.

Comment: oK. From next time , i will sure maintain this.  Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696180/open-source-ocr-library-for-arabic  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003630/open-source-ocr-for-arabic

Answer (score 1):

SAKHR has a commercial offering --I believe a Lib; standalone app; and a web app! Google sakhr for their website!  Hopefully, Google through their support for OCRopus will include arabization in future development.

Answer (score 0):

ABBYY OCR engine [supports arabic text recognition](http://www.abbyy.com/ocr_sdk_windows/technical_specifications/ocr_languages/) and it provides api for java, vb.net, c#, etc. It's free to try, trial version can be requested [here](http://www.abbyy.com/sdk/fre/request?purpose=trial). I work @ ABBYY and can provide you some more details on our engines if necessary.

Alternatively, you may want to have a look at http://ocrsdk.com, it's a website that lets you upload images through web API and sends you back OCRed data. It has a 90 days free trial without any upfront charges and [supports arabic ocr as well](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/specifications/recognition-languages/arabic-ocr-library/).

Comment: oh dear abbyy doesnt support arabic, they are going to release arabic in this year end

Comment: Bhuvan, please check the link to ABBYY web site in the Nikolay's answer. It says that it has Arabic Technical Preview supported.